# qemu-sparc vs qemu-system-sparc

Tags: centos, qemu, sparc

I installed CentOS 7.6 then installed all things QEMU on my machine. I have a SPARC image I need to bringing up in a VM. I've been using ***qemu-system-sparc***.

```
$ qemu-system-sparc -m 256 -hda solaris_v2-qemu_v2.2.0.disk -nographic -bios ./openbios-sparc32
```

This is on a box on which I have Fedora-30 installed.

Can I use **qemu-sparc** to bring up my Solaris image: ***solaris_v2-qemu_v2.2.0.disk*** ?

If so, how?

BTW, ***qemu-sparc*** come with (on CentOS 7.6):

```
$ sudo yum install qemu*
```

*PS> I've tried to install **qemu-system-sparc** on my CentOS box but ended up in a never-ending whack-a-mole game of dependencies.*

Comment: You need the **qemu-system-sparc**.  It should install directly from the CentOS repos without any trouble, but yes, with some dependencies - this is expected.

Answer (score 4):

After a great deal of web searches, I found [this](https://joel.porquet.org/wiki/hacking/qemu_sparc/):

> **QEMU as an userspace emulator**
>
> QEMU usually comes in two flavors: *qemu-system-** are system emulators
> (able to run entire operating systems as seen in the previous
> section), while *qemu-** are userspace emulators (only able to run
> userspace applications).
>
> QEMU as an userspace emulator is thus able to directly execute a SPARC
> application, by emulating the syscalls that the application requests.
>
> **Among the greatest features of this approach are:**
>
> The output of application is directly displayed in the terminal,
> Arguments to applications are directly given through the command line,
> QEMU returns the return code of applications, etc. QEMU really just
> acts as a wrapper around the application, as time or nice do.
>
> The only complicated thing you have to do in this approach is to
> compile a cross-toolchain for SPARC, so SPARC programs can be compiled
> on the host computer. Such a cross-toolchain can be generated by using
> the fabulous *crosstool-ng*.

So the answer appears to be: no, you **CANNOT** use *qemu-sparc* to run your image in a VM.

Comment: Source of the quote? Edited the answer to add what I think is the original source.

Answer (score 0):

You need the qemu-system-sparc, wich will "emulate" a sparc system.
qemu-sparc will only emulate the CPU and syscalls, thus a SPARC compiled program (that you can extract from your disk image if needed) will run on non-sparc hosts, while most syscalls be "translated" by qemu into your host syscalls, thus a SPARC program can run on said host. file io, kernel stuff, it mostly get translated and run on your host. Handy for debugging or reverse engineering.

Try:

```
yum install qemu-kvm
```

The dependencies are required ofcourse. Not very usefull in your case but you could also compile qemu yourself, maybe the dependencies overlap:
`git glib2-devel libfdt-devel pixman-devel zlib-devel`